# Erro ao tentar compilar aspecto no IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, orientação-a-aspectos

Esta é minha primeira pergunta neste site, tentarei ser sucinto.
Eu estou trabalhando com programação orientada a aspecto, já trabalhava usando o Eclipse. Porém, ao tentar fazer o mesmo usado o IntelliJ IDEA, me deparei com o seguinte erro:

```
Information:19/03/18 19:04 - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 12s 856ms Error:ajc: invalid source option, source is either '1.3' or '1.4': 1.9 Error:Internal error: bad args
```

Este exemplo foi retirado deste [site](http://tzachsolomon.blogspot.com.br/2015/08/how-to-create-hello-world-with-intellij.html) , fiz exatamente como está, à exceção do passo 18( ao invés de selecionar todo o `.jar` baixado, selecionei apenas o `aspectjrt.jar` como descrito neste [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/aspectj.html))

Esta é a configuração de minha máquina:

`Linux renan-Inspiron-3437 4.13.0-36-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 20:07:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)`

Este é o código fonte da aplicação que estou tentando executar:

```
public aspect World {

    pointcut greeting() : execution (* Hello.sayHello(..));

    after() returning() : greeting() {
        System.out.println("World");
    }
}

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sayHello();
    }

    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.print("Hello ");
    }
}
```

Esta são algumas imagens da configuração de minha IDE:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deste já agradeço a quem se dispor a me ajudar.

Comment: O método `sayHello()` na classe `Hello` não recebe parâmetros!! Porque está passando `..` na linha `execution (* Hello.sayHello(..));` ?

Comment: A sintaxe do pointcut `greeting()` no aspecto `World` quer dizer: selecione um método com assinatura `sayHello` na classe `Hello` independente  dos argumentos que este método receba (por isso `..`).  Após isso, o advice é executado e tenho a saída: `Hello World` (No eclipse funciona).